# Closest number to 1.22

Tags: floating-point

Given:

```
1 bit for sign
3 bits for exp
4 bits for fract
```

How to find the closest floating-point number to `1.22` ??

Comment: $1.22$ is a number

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo, 1.22 cannot be represented as a representation of the mentioned bits - fractional part would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The values of the sign bit and the exponent ought to be obvious. So the only question is what the mantissa ought to be. But there are only 4 bits in the mantissa. So even if you don't know what to try, you could just try all 16 possible mantissas and see which one comes closest.